# Powershell Folder Inheritence problem

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I am having problems with a powershell script i basically trying to reset the permission on a folder, by removing the following groups

- NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
- BUILTIN\Users

If i manually change the folder to not inherit from it parent the script works, I have look through google to find best way of removing the inheritance via a script the script compiles but not do anything.

This is the command i am using

```
$WebsiteACL =Get-Acl -Path "C:\websites"
$WebsiteACL.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)
```

Does anyone have any sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find Get-Acl and Set-Acl still too much of a PITA to use (and I'm a C# dev).  You can use icacls.exe to accomplish your task easily:

```
icacls C:\temp\foo /inheritance:d
```

It also supports removing groups.  Check out its usage: `icacls /?`.

Comment: thanks keith, get-acl / set-scl is pita, will give that i try

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Acl/Set-Acl` can be a royal pain unless you're the owner of the object you're trying to change permissions on -- even if you're an Administrator. If you want to change an ACL on an object you don't own you have to have the **SeBackupPrivilege** enabled for your identity/account. The only easy way I know of to modify system privileges is install **PowerShell Community Extensions** and use `Get/Set-Privilege`. I really don't understand why this limitation exists but it does.

With that said, using `icacls` works very well under most conditions. There is a bug if you're setting permissions on a directory accessed through a share with Access Based Enumeration enabled. Everyone does this right? ;)

Touching a directory underneath an ABE controlled share with icacls causes the directory to disappear even if you still have permissions to that directory. If you use the Windows Explorer ACL editor to read and (re)apply the permissions set with icacls the directory is visible again.

After much head scratching it was determined that icacls was doing something to the **synchronize** bit. Without **synchronize** ABE causes the directory to be invisible. The simplest workaround would be to not use ABE but in our environment disabling ABE is not an option.

Another solution is use `SetACL.exe` which you can download from SourceForge. It has a very complicated syntax, imho, but is really powerful. It's also available as a OCX so you can script it via PowerShell.